# Is there a function that can make a cell in a sheet connected to another cell in another sheet, with the same info but a different cell location

Tags: google-sheets

To explain properly. Lets say that you have Sheet "Employees", with 50 employees total. On row 18, cell A, you have Dave.
On the same sheet, you have a checkbox that once pressed will blur out Dave's name to show that he left the company.

Lets say that you have another sheet named "Activity", and there you also have the employees, but Dave on that sheet is on **Row 42**, Cell A.

Is there a way for me, that once i press the check box, Dave and ONLY Dave will get blurred out, both on Row 18 of the "Employees" Sheet, and on Row 42 of the " Activity" sheet without needing to a formula those cells specifically?

Comment: Index() with match() or conditional formatting. You need to know which you are using or read the help files in both.

Comment: @BigBen.  Im using google sheets for this, not excel.

Answer (score 1):

there are various ways how to tackle it... for example with conditional formatting:

```
=REGEXMATCH(D2, TEXTJOIN("|", 1, 
 FILTER(INDIRECT("Employees!A:A"), INDIRECT("Employees!B:B")=TRUE)))
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, thanks for suggesting this, but i need to be cross-sheets.

Comment: The activity sheet is a separate sheet from the employee sheet, its not just a small sub-section of the employee one

Comment: @Scylla yes. the proposed solution is meant to be used in Activity sheet. don't mind the photoshopped picture and try the formula.